# Smallest spectral radius of signed Petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, signed-graphs

I have come across a question that requires finding the smallest spectral radius of a signed Petersen graph, i.e., find the smallest  $p \geq 0$ such that there exists a signed adjacency matrix of the Petersen graph whose eigenvalues lie in the interval $[-p,p]$.

I have come across the paper [Six signed Petersen graphs, and their automorphisms](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2011.12.010) by Thomas Zaslavsky. Even though I can generate the spectral radius for the 6 equivalence classes, is there a shorter way to find it algebraically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.